# How to extract hostname from a url in a txt file?

Tags: delphi, url

I have several urls in a text file and want to extract just their hostnames and save them back to the same file.

ex:

```
https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/blob/master/
```

I need just the hostname:

```
github.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just looking for straight string parsing only? If so, look at Indy's `TIdURI` class. Or are you wanting to validate the URLs actually work online? If so, look at Indy's `TIdHTTP` component.

Comment: If you're using wininet there's also [`InternetCrackUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, i wants remove all complete path of url and http/https prefix of each string in each line of txt file. Result must be: `github.com` like showed above.

Comment: The question was edited to better understand.

Comment: @MarcioGomes I edited the question to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to extract the domain from a http (or https) URL. No validation is performed on the supplied URL, it is expected to be a full, valid http/https URL.

```
FUNCTION ExtractDomain(CONST URL : STRING) : STRING;
  VAR
    P : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:=URL;
    IF COPY(Result,1,7)='http://' THEN DELETE(Result,1,7);
    IF COPY(Result,1,8)='https://' THEN DELETE(Result,1,8);
    P:=POS('/',Result);
    IF P>0 THEN SetLength(Result,PRED(P))
  END;
```

Comment: If you want to handle other URL schemes0 besides just HTTP/S, use `Pos(':')` instead of `Copy()` (and BTW, Delphi has `AnsiStartsStr()` and `StartsText()` functions for checking if a string starts with a given substring)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I know of the functions, but am not sure how far back they go. The code given works on all versions of Delphi, all the way back to v6 and perhaps even earlier (can't remember when SetLength was introduced).

Comment: `AnsiStartsText()` and `AnsiStartsStr()` are in the `StrUtils` unit in v6+. `StartsText()` and `StartsStr()` are in the `StrUtils` unit in 2006+.

Comment: this code does not work if someone give Http or HTTPS with Uppercase.
Thats why in my example i search for string '://

Answer (score 2):

```
      function extractdomain(url : string) : string;
           var
             p : cardinal;
           begin 
             result:=''; 
             if trim(url)='' then exit;
             url:=trim(url)+'/';
             p:=pos('://',url);
             if p>0 then delete(url,1,p+pred(length('://')));
             p:=pos('/',url);
             result:=copy(url,1,pred(p));
           end;
```